# Storing variable from listbox

Tags: powershell, listbox

I'm attempting to gather user input and store it using `$contacttype` later on in my script. Originally I was using a simple text input, however I'm now trying to use a listbox to get user input instead.

Originally I was doing this:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null
$contacttype = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter the contact type", " ")
```

However, I'm now trying to use a listbox with something like:

```
$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40) 
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$listBox.Height = 80

[void] $listBox.Items.Add("VPN")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("Phone")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("E-mail")

$form.Controls.Add($listBox) 

$form.Topmost = $True

$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $x = $listBox.SelectedItem
    $x
}
```

How do I make sure `$contacttype` is populated with the output from the selected listbox item?

Comment: this is not c# code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your answer, you just need to make sure you return your result to the `$contacttype` variable. However the code you provided wasn't complete, it didn't include the part that initiated `$form` or add an OK button to trigger the ok result.

Here's a complete version that I've also moved in to a function to show how you could make this a little more reusable:

```
Function Invoke-ListForm {
    Param(
        [string[]] $ListItem
    )

    $Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form

    $listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
    $listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40) 
    $listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
    $listBox.Height = 80

    ForEach ($Item in $ListItem) {
        [void] $listBox.Items.Add($Item)
    }

    $listBox.Add_Click({ $listBox.SelectedItem })
    $Form.Controls.Add($listBox) 

    $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
    $OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $OKButton.Text = "OK"
    $OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK

    $Form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
    $Form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

    $Form.Topmost = $True
    $Result = $form.ShowDialog()

    if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
    {
        $listBox.SelectedItem
    }
}

$ContactType = Invoke-ListForm VPN,Phone,E-mail
$ContactType
```

Comment: I kept that out just to avoid it becoming a huge amount of code but thank you for adding to this.

Comment: Understood, but worth bearing in mind for the future its easier for people to help you if you provide a complete/functional example to work from (that you've made as minimal as possible). This is commonly referred to as an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Was unaware, a good point and hopefully will help those in future with a similar issue/problem.